# Consuming JWT with JQuery, continually getting an error

Tags: jquery, node.js, jwt

I'm currently building an API with NodeJS using JSONWebtoken. When I try consuming with the token in the header I receive error 403 and it goes directly to the else statement in the code below, which means token is not there at all.

Here is how I get token on server-side:

```
router.use(function(req, res, next){

var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

  //decode token
  if(token)   {
    jwt.verify(token, app.get('secretKey'), function(err, decoded){
      if(err)
        return res.json({ success:false, message: 'failed, token problem'});
      else {
        req.decoded = decoded;
        next();
      }
    });
  }else {
    return res.status(403).send({
      success:false,
      message: 'token not provided'
    })
  }
});
```

on client-side, I'm using JQuery and save it in cookie:

1. token as data works:

   ```
   $.ajax({
     type:'GET',
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     url :"http://localhost:3000/api/users",
     data : {
       token : $.cookie('token')
     },
     success: function(data, status) {
       console.log("Status " + status);
       console.log(data);
     }
   });
   ```
2. token as parameter works too

   ```
   $.get("http://localhost:3000/api/users?token=" + $.cookie('token'))
    .done(function(data){
      console.log(data);
    });
   ```
3. Here is the problem, using header

   ```
   $.ajax({
     type:'GET',
     url :"http://localhost:3000/api/users",
     beforeSend: function(xhr) {
       xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + $.cookie('token'));
     },
     success: function(data, status) {
       console.log("Status " + status);
       console.log(data);
     }
   });
   ```

I also tried add x-access-token as header on ajaxSetup

```
$.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
            'x-access-token': $.cookie('token')
          }
        });
```

I keep getting 403, which is token not provided, I think it is a CORS issue so i tried to use CORS npm package https://github.com/expressjs/cors doesn't work, I tried to implement this.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});
```

//update information on 22 August 2016

If I use the following in Safari, it works:

```
  $.ajax({
      type:'GET',
      url :"http://localhost:3000/api/users",
      headers : { "Authorization" : $.cookie('token') },
      success: function(data, status) {
        console.log("Status " + status);
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
```

But some how it goes to both if and else statement, so it responds to the next route but also shows the 403 message.

Comment: Do you have server side code? If you ran the verification with the other methods and they were successful but your cookie was not, did you remember to remove `Bearer` from the cookie before validating the token?

Comment: @Mike i update the server-code the problem is it goes directly to the else statement, which means token not there at all

Comment: try using object in ajax  headers: {         'X-Auth-Token' : token }  OR .. headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $.cookie('token')
  }, ALSO TRY adding in headers  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'

Comment: @Hilmanrdn do you have a snippet of the failing server-side code? I think it would make it easier to diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 0):

i change my cors setting by using a node package

```
https://github.com/expressjs/cors
```

so far it works by using it

```
$.ajax({
          type:'GET',
          url :"http://localhost:3000/api/users",
          headers: {'x-access-token': $.cookie('token')},
          success: function(data, status) {
            console.log("Status " + status);
            console.log(data);
          }
        });
```